# IIS 10 - How to enable URL redirection based on Port

Tags: url, iis

I have two domain names created for same VM. For example.
http://app1.domain.com
http://app2.domain.com

Currently both are pointing to port 80 and the application works fine.
My requirement is as below:

1. When i open http://app1.domain.com, it should open the application at port 80 (default port).
2. When i opein http://app2.domain.com, it should open a different application at port 90.

How can i do that? i tried Url Rewrite/Redirect but could not make it work. I am new to IIS functionality. Can someone help with any example/screenshots?

Comment: is your issue is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You could use bwlo URL rewrite rule:

```
 <rule name="rule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^app1.domain.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:80" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="rule2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^app2.domain.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:90" />
            </rule>
```

[image]

[image]